# How to redirect to any webresource on button click in MS Dynamics CRM Online?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing an problem when I redirect to any HTML webresource.

I have added a HTML page as webresource name "new_My_ProductList" in solution.

I have created a button "Go To My Product" in Ribbon and set following function of JS file as command of it. It will open window.

```
function RedirectToLowStockList() {
          window.open('WebResources/new_My_ProductList', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1,menubar=no,height=500,width=1000,resizable=1,toolbar=no,status=1');
}
```

Above function is working perfectly whenever URL is like: "https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com/WebResources/new_My_ProductList"

But sometimes it generate wrong URL and show Error 404

Here is example of wrong URL:

1- https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com/_root/WebResources/new_My_ProductList

2- https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com/_form/WebResources/new_My_ProductList

We can see that there are 2 key word "_root" and "_form" automatically added in URL.

Can anybody please suggest me solution? If above way not appropriate, can anybody please suggest me appropriate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenWebResource) function instead.

```
Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(webResourceName,webResourceData,width, height)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass the details `_blank` and scroll?

Comment: @NanjiMange, I don't think you get those options in the SDK function, but the SDK function is guarenteed to work.

Comment: Thank you. I am happy there are some people who can help on StackOverFlow for MS CRM.

Answer (score 2):

Your ribbon should support the **$webresource:** directive. From [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473.aspx):

> When possible, use the $webresource directive. Only references that use the $webresource directive in the site map or ribbon commands will establish dependencies. Dependencies are not created when web resources reference each other.

If you're unfamiliar with editing solution XML, you can install [this Ribbon Workbench](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx) to help you.

If you're still unsure, you can use `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(webResourceName, webResourceData, width, height)`. Its use is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenWebResource).

Comment: Hi Dave, Can you please let me know how to open WebResouce in new windows in `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource()`? Currently it opens in new Tab.